# Youtube shortcode not displaying

Tags: wordpress, youtube, shortcode

Youtube shortcodes will not display on localhost WordPress site when posted in text editor or plugin. Shortcode displayed twice before it just stopped working.

Shortcode format:

```
[fts_youtube vid_count=5 large_vid=yes large_vid_title=yes 
large_vid_description=no thumbs_play_in_iframe=yes vids_in_row=6 
omit_first_thumbnail=no space_between_videos=1px force_columns=no 
maxres_thumbnail_images=yes thumbs_wrap_color=#000 
channel_id=UCkbTTGoBpjX8ogXHCt-aegw]
```

Any solutions to resolve youtube shortcodes not displaying on WordPress?

Comment: what plugin are you using? Is it activated??

Comment: Tried various plugins and the base text editor. Currently attempting with the Feed Them Social by SlickRemix.

Comment: Is it activated? And are there any errors in debug.log? or in javascript?

Comment: It is activated and there are currently no errors displaying. Yesterday I was getting an errors that stated: 

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED BY CLIENT`

Comment: post your content.php code here

Comment: Next, do the following:

1. Use default WordPress theme.

2. If still not working - deactivate all other plugins

3. If still not working - use [fts short code] with MINIMAL parameters (defaults only)

Please let us know the results

Comment: @Vel I'm unsure on how to find that code? New to this

Comment: which theme you are using?

Comment: Try with Some other plugins https://wordpress.org/plugins/youtube-embed/

Comment: @Vel this is the current theme: http://www.akshitsethi.com/wordpress-theme/moscow.php

Comment: @Mulli Tried your 3 troubleshooting steps and none resolved the issue.

Comment: do you have API key?

Comment: @Vel I do, generated an API from Youtube Data API v3

Comment: its working fine for me with moscow theme

Comment: @HarshKhareit doesn't work with any plugin or text editor

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have created Youtube API key and put it in your plugin setting.

You can check this tutorial https://www.slickremix.com/docs/get-api-key-for-youtube/

and https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

Comment: Reset WordPress completely and the plugin will work briefly but a new page is added the gallery will break and not display. This occurs with all plugins not just the Feed Them Social gallery.